# Entity state error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project at the minute and i am getting an error with entity state modified, i have included the code and highlighted the line of code in bold. This is the error i am getting, could anybody help me please

> Error 4   The type or namespace name 'EntityState' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\podge\Desktop\SportsStore\SportsStore\Models\Repository\Repository.cs  35  27  SportsStore

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace SportsStore.Models.Repository
{

  public class Repository {
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products {
      get { return context.Products; }
    }


    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
    {
      get
      {
        return context.Orders
          .Include(o => o.OrderLines
          .Select(ol => ol.Product));
      }
    }

    public void SaveOrder(Order order)
    {
      if (order.OrderId == 0)
      {
        order = context.Orders.Add(order);
        foreach (OrderLine line in order.OrderLines)
        {
          context.Entry(line.Product).State
          **= System.Data.EntityState.Modified;**

        } 
      }
      else
      {
        Order dbOrder = context.Orders.Find(order.OrderId);
        if (dbOrder != null)
        {
          dbOrder.Name = order.Name;
          dbOrder.Line1 = order.Line1;
          dbOrder.Line2 = order.Line2;
          dbOrder.Line3 = order.Line3;
          dbOrder.City = order.City;
          dbOrder.State = order.State;
          dbOrder.GiftWrap = order.GiftWrap;
          dbOrder.Dispatched = order.Dispatched;
        }
      }
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`EntityState` belongs to `System.Data.Entity` namespace, not `System.Data`. But in your code you have used it like `System.Data.EntityState`

You already have a `using` statement for `System.Data.Entity` namespace on the top part of your file. So you you do not need the fully qualified name. you may simply use `EntityState.Modified`

**Replace**

```
context.Entry(line.Product).State= System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

**with**

```
context.Entry(line.Product).State= EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the NuGet Manager update your entityFramework version